# Настроить Autocomplete mui

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, mui

У меня есть автокомплит от матириал ю ай

```
<Autocomplete
  id="instruments"
  options={allInstruments}
  disabled={allInstruments.length === 0}
  value={instrument}
  onChange={(event, newValue) => handleInstruments(newValue)}
  defaultValue={allInstruments[0]}
  size="small"
  sx={{ mt: 0.2, flexGrow: 2 }}
  getOptionLabel={(tool: InstrumentInfo) => tool.title}
  isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.code === value}
  renderOption={(props, option) => (
    <li {...props}>
      <StyledBox className={option.isLastUsed ? 'topFive' : ''}>
        {option.title}
      </StyledBox>
    </li>
  )}
  renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} label="Инструменты" />}
/>
```

в options я передаю массив данных allInstruments, там есть несколько инструментов для примера: молоток, отвертка, дрель... и так же есть пункт "Все инструменты"
Autocomplete работает так, что если я ввожу "м", то мне выдается молоток, если "О" - отвертка, если "в"/"все" - то все инструменты, можно ли сделать так, чтобы когда я писал "м" мне выдавалось бы сначало Все инструменты, а затем только то что подходит под фильтр, т е молоток ?